# How can I debug to find out why my ExtJS data store is not loading?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an ExtJS data store that queries the server for data.  I can see the JSON data in the Chrome network response tab, but when I check the size of the store in the console tab using `Ext.getStore("ExampleStore").data.length`, the value is always zero.  There are no Javascript errors reported on the page.  Is there a better way to debug the data loading into the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach event callbacks on the store's [`load`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) event in ExtJS 1.1.0 and higher and the proxy's [`exception`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-event-exception) event in ExtJS 3.4.0 and higher.  For older versions of ExtJS back to 1.1.0, you can use the store's [`loadexception`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-loadexception) event.  From any of those callbacks, it's easy to place a breakpoint and figure out what's going on.

```
Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    storeId: "ExampleStore"
    // Other properties removed for brevity
}).on({
    load: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
        alert("The load event was called");
    },
    exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
        alert("The exception event was called");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recomend you to use Fire Bug for Fire Fox

https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/firebug/

In my opinion it gives more information about errors and better formatting, I do like to test in Chrome ('cos it is faster) but when I get an error I can't understand I run to FireBug

You can do a `console.log(myStore);` and from there explore the object's DOM

Also look at Store methods like getCount and getTotalCount

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you implement ExtJS into your application, but to all the above, I can add that you can use to debug file ext-all-debug-w-comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all-debug-w-comments.js"></ script>
```

This will make the error reports displayed in the console much more informative.